# Formulation of convex constrained optimization problem (SVR)

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with my formulation of a certain problem, as all other instances of it were formulated slightly differently.

The problem (SVR problem, If you're familiar with it) is as follows:given $\{x^{(i)},y_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$, We would like to find a hyperplane, defined by $\langle w,x\rangle +b=0$ which minimizes the $l_2$ norm of $w$ plus the sum (over $i$) of the loss defined by:
$$loss(w,b;x^{(i)})=[\left|\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle +b -y_i\right|-\epsilon ]_+
$$

I would formulate the problem as follows:
$$\min_{w,b,\xi_i} \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{m}\xi_i$$
$$s.t.\cases{\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle +b-y_i-\epsilon\leq\xi_i\cr y_i-\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle -b-\epsilon\leq\xi_i\cr \xi_i\geq 0} i=1,...,m
$$
But every formulation I've seen uses separate variables $\xi_i,\xi_i^* \geq 0$ for the first 2 constraints:
$$\min_{w,b,\xi_i} \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{m}(\xi_i + \xi_i^*)$$
$$s.t. \cases{\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle +b-y_i-\epsilon\leq\xi_i\cr y_i-\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle -b-\epsilon\leq\xi_i^*\cr \xi_i,\xi_i^*\geq 0} i=1,...,m
$$
What's wrong with my way? I'm thinking it might have something to do with the KKT conditions (since we want to formulate it using the multipliers and get a problem with a global minimum). I have some basic understanding of the KKT conditions, but I don't fully understand all the constraints qualifications (Which I assume might be the problem)

Comment: Your way looks good. If $z_i=<w,x^i>+b-y_i$ then $loss_i = [|z_i|-\epsilon]_+$ and so $z_i - \epsilon \leq loss_i$ and $-z_i - \epsilon \leq loss_i$, which are captured in your constraints.So your problem seeks to minimize $(1/2)||w||^2 + \sum_i loss_i$.

Comment: I think you would need to add the $<w,x>+b=0$ constraint though.  I don't know what the "other formulation" is or if it has some advantages.  Your problem indeed looks convex.

Comment: @Michael Well, the question persists then... I'm hoping to find someone who is by chance familiar with SVR and convex optimization in general to explain this... I haven't found a detailed explanation of the formulation, only a description of the problem and then a formal formulation like mine except with the noted changes. We won't need the constraint $\langle w,x\rangle +b=0 $ though, it's just the definition of a hyperplane, we don't have some $x$ for which we demand this.

Comment: I see no problem at all with your formulation. In fact, you don't even need $\xi_i\geq 0$. It is implied by the other two. I'll bet that a formulation that uses $\xi_i^*$ is less efficient than yours. But in fact, we *can't* answer the question fully without seeing the *exact* form of the alternate formulation.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I thought I didn't need $\xi_i \geq 0$ too at first, but then I realized - If we have, for example, $\langle w,x^{(i)}\rangle +b =0$ for some $x^{(i)}$, we get that $\xi_i$ can (and will, because we minimize by it too) become $-\epsilon$, which we don't want. I will update with the other formulation.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I agree you still need $\xi_i\geq 0$. Please add the objective function to the alternative problem.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Done. Sorry, forgot the objective also changes a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Then as written I am certain the extra variables are unnecessary. Either one or the other of $\xi_i$, $\xi_i^*$ will be zero at the optimum. (Or both.)

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGrant that your primal is simpler, but I think it leads to a (slightly) more complicated dual. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual of your new primal problem is almost the same as the standard dual, with one difference.   To see this, I am following the work on this link (but modifying it to your new primal):  http://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf

Under your *new* problem, the Lagrangian is (with multipliers $\lambda_i, \mu_i, \theta_i$):

\begin{align}
&L = \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 + \sum_i \xi_i \\
&+ \sum_i \lambda_i [w^T x^i + b - y_i - \epsilon - \xi_i] \\
&+ \sum_i \mu_i [y_i - w^T x^i - b - \epsilon - \xi_i] \\
&-\sum_i \theta_i \xi_i
\end{align}

where $w^T$ is the transpose of vector $w$. 
You now use duality concepts to compute $\sup_{\lambda \geq 0 , \mu \geq 0, \theta \geq 0} \left[\inf_{w, \xi, b} L\right]$.  Since we must have an infimum over $w$ we can take $\partial/\partial w_j$ to get (similar to equation (8) in the paper):

$$ w = \sum_i (\mu_i - \lambda_i)x^i $$

Since we must take an infimum over $b$, the answer is $-\infty$ unless (similar to equation (7) in the paper):

$$ \sum_i (\lambda_i - \mu_i) = 0 $$

and so we must choose the multipliers to satisfy the above to avoid a $-\infty$ infimum.   Similarly, since we take an infimum over $\xi_i$ we must have (similar to equation (9)):

$$  1 = \lambda_i + \mu_i + \theta_i $$

Plugging these back into the Lagrangian $L$, simplifying, and taking the outer maximization gives:

\begin{align} 
&\mbox{Maximize:} -\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j (\mu_i-\lambda_i)(\mu_j-\lambda_j)x_i^Tx_j - \epsilon\sum_i(\lambda_i + \mu_i) + \sum_i y^i (\mu_i-\lambda_i) \\
&\mbox{Subject to:} \sum_i (\lambda_i-\mu_i) = 0 \: \: , \: \: \lambda_i \geq 0 \: \: \forall i \: \: , \: \: \mu_i \geq 0 \: \: \forall i \: \: , \: \: \lambda_i + \mu_i \leq 1 \: \: \forall i 
\end{align}

where the $\lambda_i + \mu_i \leq 1 $ constraint comes from $\lambda_i + \mu_i = 1 - \theta_i$ and $\theta_i\geq 0$.  The only difference between this new dual problem and the standard one given in equation (10) of the paper is that, there, we would get separate constraints $\lambda_i \in [0,1]$ and $\mu_i \in [0,1]$ rather than the combined constraint $\lambda_i + \mu_i \leq 1$. I think the separate constraints are a bit easier, and so your formulation has a simpler primal (as Michael Grant also mentioned), but a slightly more complicated dual.